# Graphs of Chi-squared densities

Tags: density-function, chi-squared

This is my first post, so I hope this question belongs here (and isn't too strange)
I've seen a graphic where Chi-squared densities with different degrees of freedom were plotted and I was wondering why the Graphs for densities with one and two degrees are strictly decreasing whereas from three degrees on it is unimodal. Coming from the the density formula I do understand it but intuitively as a sum of squared standard normal random variables I do not. Shouldn't zero be always the "most likely" outcome? Thanks for helping!

Comment: I like your question because my question is totally opposite to your :-) Shouldn't NOT zero be always the correct value for x=0 and for any degree of freedom (=k)  even for k > 2?